# Android Live Wallpaper Interaction with Widgets And Tell Wallpaper where widgets are placed

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-intent, live-wallpaper

Is there functionality in teh live Wallpaper for the service to know where widgets are placed on the homescreen and the size of the widgets? For instance If I created a Live Wallpaper that changed based on widget position is that possible?

Also I want to make a widget with buttons that manipulate the live wallpaper, would I use the Intent Service for this? or what is the best way to interact with a live wallpaper through a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wallpaper has nothing to do with drawing widgets. There is now way to make a livewallpaper aware of homescreen objects without modifying the firmware or possibly making your own homescreen

Comment: really? seems like i could get the process that are running and ask them for their position, or talk directly to the homescreen for this info

Comment: You could theoretically talk to the homescreen for the info, but you'd have to get whatever homescreen application developer to expose an API to get that info. Getting the running process doesn't do any good because the process has no idea where it's being drawn at with respsect to the homescreen.